# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que ante un evento Key, primero se agregue la letra al entry y luego se ejecute la función? en Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un entry y quiero que cada vez que presione una tecla, se imprima en consola el contenido, el tema es que al escribir primero se hace la función y luego se agrega la letra al entry, EJ: si primero presiono a se me imprime vacío, y si luego presiono b, solo se imprime a.

y me gustaría que fuera al revés, que si toco a, se imprima a

````
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.config(width=300, height=200)
root.title("Mi aplicación")
entry = ttk.Entry(root)
entry.bind("<Key>", lambda x: print(entry.get()))
entry.place(x=50, y=50, width=150)
root.mainloop() ```
````

Comment: Pareciera que el evento Key se está ejecutando antes de que el Entry sea modificado. Probaste con KeyRelease (que se ejecuta cuando se suelta la tecla). Alternativamente, podés usar una variable de control (como StringVar) y usar su método trace que se ejecutará cuando el contenido de esa variable sea modificado.

Comment: Igual, algo me dice que esto es un [problema xy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY). Tengo la suposición que imprimir en consola en contenido es por motivos de prueba. Que estas queriendo lograr a partir de detectar cuando se presiona la tecla, más allá de imprimir en consola enlcontenido? Si querés validar el contenido del Entry (es decir, restringir que caracteres y en que formato escribir), hay mejores formas de lograrlo.

Answer (score 0):

ahhh lo que tu te estas quejando es que no te esta imprimiendo la tecla que oprimiste sino que te obliga a teclear otra para que el print la muestre.

Esto ocurre porque el Evento que estas usando esta mal utilizado, debes cambiar Key po KeyRelease, de esa forma el evento se genera en el momento que sueltas la tecla y no cuando la oprimes.

```
entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda x: print(entry.get()))
```

Asi ya deberia imprimirse en la consola de python la tecla y no debes escribir una nueva para que aparezca.